# How to insert a linebreak into a Stack Overflow chat?

Tags: support, chat

Today, I encountered an issue while posting in the Stack Overflow chat for the first time.
I wanted to insert a linebreak (new line), but sent my message instead, by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
After deleting my message and a few googling around, I didn't find anything, even in the FAQ and the help, and decided to experiment around.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the result of my experiment: `Shift+Enter` will insert a new line.
`Ctrl+Enter`, as well as `Enter` will send your message.

Also, sending multiple successive messages will visually append them with a linebreak in between, although they are still considered as different messages.

I hope this helps someone else.